# Biztalk multiple continuous calls to webservices

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Here is the problem:
Biztalk application should get data from  webservice into two steps:

1.Request list of changed clients  **GetChangedClients(date)** and receive list in format:

```
    <clients>
        <client id='C1'>
        <client id='C2'>
        ....
        <client id='CN'>
    </clients>
```

2.After receiving list of clients Biztalk will issue one call per client  like

```
getChanges("C1")
getChanges("C2")
    ....
getChanges("CN")
```

3.After changes messages received they will be passed to WCF-port.

**Question:**
What would be the best way to build this into biztalk 
(building orchestration with a loop, call component to create multiple messages with clientid, create custom adapter ) ?

Comment: Do the changes to 'client' have to be done in order or can they run parallel?

Comment: Clients can run parallel

Comment: Can you change that webservice? I think the best solution is to make that service send you a batch of changed clients, so you can use envelope schema to disassemble it and manage clients in parallel.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not controlling web-service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the scatter-gatherer pattern would work well for this.  In your orchestration split the clients xml document into individual client messages, then publish these to a orchestration that handles them along with a correlation token.  The orchestration that does the individual calls and sends the response back to the controlling orchestration.  An example can be found at http://www.richardhallgren.com/a-loosely-coupled-scatter-and-gather-implementation-in-biztalk-2006/

Another place for an example of this is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cvidotto/archive/2006/12/18/biztalk-server-2006-code-samples-awesome.aspx.  Search for Implementing Scatter and Gather Pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I really like this example and will try to implement this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest way to this, is to use [Partner Direct Ports in BizTalk](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BizTalk-the-Partner-Direct-b4c2b47d).